# Using localhost to test Facebook canvas app

Tags: facebook

I want to create and test an app initially from localhost (were I run Ruby on Rails or Glassfish).  I have read many postings about how to do this and NONE work. I have tried all the solutions discussed on stackoverflow and  other sites.

Does anyone have a current method that does work (2015)?

Following did not work

1) in Canvas URL  http://localhost:3000/users/index/  with and without localhost as domains
2) Tried editing the Advanced tab to add redirect URL to same URL.

What happens is I get a blank screen (I have even tried really simple hello world type apps that run locally so it should work with facebook).

Thank you,
Lynne

Comment: You need to configure Secure Canvas URL.

Answer (score 0):

you have to configure `secure canvas URL` for canvas apps . it is mandatory and it has to be a **https URL**.

Answer (score 0):

edit: This is actually a lot easier than I thought. I found [this](https://gist.github.com/dergachev/7028596) python script that creates a local https server. The only issue was that facebook is sending a `POST` request on the canvas page, and this server doesn't support `POST` requests, so [I modified it a bit](https://gist.github.com/jespertheend/2bfe52dc9881dc8fc1f32ff6ed41116c) and now it handles the facebook canvas page correctly.

You don't need a domain, and in the script it tells you how to generate the self signed certificate. In the facebook app settings you can set `https://localhost:4443/` as canvas url.

---

old post:

It is possible but it's a bit of a hassle. You can set a dns to `127.0.0.1` and use that. So if you own `example.com`, you can create an A DNS record for `localhost.example.com` and set it to `127.0.0.1`.

The difficult part is that you have to find some way to create a certificate for this domain. If you want an official cert, the easiest option out there is Let's Encrypt. Verification of your domain through an https server is going to be difficult, since the Let's Encrypt servers will try to contact `127.0.0.1`. So you're probably better of using DNS challenge validation. Another option would be a self signed certificate, which is a whole different story.

The last step is to find a server that can host https and use the certificates you generated.